# how to add items to the list only if it is not already in the list.Then warn the user if data is not inserted into the model

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I should only add items that isn't already in the QListview then sort the list, if the item is in the list a messages should tell the user and the item is not added.

I have tried comparing the items in the list but I get an errors.
                                             ^
I also added 'QStringListModel::data..'.

```
void BookInput::output()
{

    QModelIndex pos = model->index(1);
QString item = model->data(0,Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();

  // QString yes = " string";
   //QString row1 = model->data(0, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
   // QMessageBox::information(0, "Message", QString("this is the list %1")  .arg(row1) ,0);
int row = model->rowCount();



 for ( int i = 1;i<= row-1; i++)
 {
     QString otherItem = model->data(i,Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();
    if (item == other)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Message", QString("There are duplicates in the list")  ,0);

    }
 }


Struggling to produce a sorted list with no duplicates. 

          error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
          QString otherItem = model->data(i,Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();


          error: no matching function for call to'QStringListModel::data(int, 
          Qt::ItemDataRole)'QString item = model 
          >data(0,Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();
```

Comment: What is the type of `model`?

Answer (score 0):

A list with no duplicates is a set. From the documentation for [`QSet`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qset.html) :

> const_iterator QSet::insert(const T & value)
>
> Inserts item value into the set, if value isn't already in the set,
>   and returns an iterator pointing at the inserted item.
>
> See also operator<<(), remove(), and contains().

The doc seems incomplete, but I would expect that `insert` returns `QSet::end()` in case the element was already in the set before calling `insert`. In case it does not (and instead always returns an iterator to `value`) then you would have to combine `find` and `insert`.